# Why my raspberry pi can not connect to the wireless network ？

Tags: raspberry-pi, archlinux

I run the command **wifi-menu** in my archARM system ,and it already found the Wi-Fi hotspot,
but the the connection failed.

here has a photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q39Bv.jpg

note: I use the EDUP EP-N8508GS USB wireless adapter.

So now,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem on an x86 Arch system, this is what fixed it: Look in `/etc/netctl/` and find the config for your wireless connection.  Add the line `WPA_DRIVER='wext'`.  If you already have a WPA_DRIVER line, change it and make sure it is using the wext driver.  If `/etc/netctl/` doesn't exist it is because you haven't updated Arch in a while, and the files you are looking for are located in `/etc/network.d`